# Why does my MFMailComposeViewController instance only dismiss one time?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to track down the source of a bug in a cordova/phonegap plugin I wrote for creating email messages in app using a MFMailComposeViewController instance.

Everyone works fine the first time you present the the composer view.  The user can dismiss the mail composer by sending the message or canceling.  However, call `presentViewController` again renders the Cancel and Send buttons in the composer to become useless.   My delegate for `didFinishWithResult` is never calling when pressing the inoperable buttons with the second view of the controller.

Below is simplified repro of what I'm seeing (the simple storyboard has a single view containing a single UIButton wired to my `(IBAction)sendMail`).  What am I doing wrong in obj-c here?  Shouldn't I be able to show a controller, dismiss it, and show it again?

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *mailButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong) MFMailComposeViewController* picker;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    self.picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)sendMail
{
    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for the behavior you are experiencing is the MFMailComposeViewController nils it's delegate when dismissed (maybe in -viewDidDisappear:).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    self.picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Put a break point here **#breakpoint1**
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)sendMail
{
    // Put a break point here **#breakpoint2**
    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Place breakpoints at shown in the code comment above, run, and follow me as we step through your code.

1. Tap the interface button that calls your IBAction; execution halts at #breakpoint2
2. In the console type `po self.picker`
3. You'll see the mail compose VC instance is allocated
4. In the console type `po self` and then `po self.picker.delegate`
5. You'll see these both print the same object (the instance of your view controller)
6. Resume running, and tap the dismiss button on the mail compose view; execution halts at #breakpoint1
7. If you want to, inspect local and instance variables in console and then resume running
8. Tap the interface button that calls your IBAction (this is the second time); execution halts at #breakpoint2
9. In the console typ `po self.picker.delegate`
10. nil is printed to console

This delegate nil'ing behavior isn't documented in either Apple's MFMailComposeViewController class reference or the classes header. It's probably worth filing a bug report requesting clarification and better documentation. Because it's undocumented, the behavior may change in future releases. For that reason, the suggestions to create and destroy the VC as needed certainly seem like good common sense.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed walkthrough, though something doesn't add up for me.  Re: #3 `po self.delegate.picker` is always `nil` for me.  However, `po self.delegate.mailComposeDelegate` always equals the same memory address as `po self` (i.e., `ViewController`), regardless of whether the MF VC is working or not.  I'm using the iPhone 6.1 simulator...

Comment: Ah! You're right, my mistake. I was looking at the wrong property on the MFMailComposeViewController. Well, now I'm stumped, too! :-)

Comment: Giving you credit for the most informative answer and because it confirms my suspicion that the code *should* work.  I'm going to file a bug report with Apple just in case this is an iOS problem.

Comment: I this as bug report # 14706392 via Apple's Developer Connect.  Will be curious if this is an iOS bug or not.

Comment: I've duped your bug. If you hear back, please let us know what the "real" answer is. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This bit me once before. It's caused by the composer being deallocated after it's done being dismissed. To solve this I would place the composer's creation either in viewDidAppear:, or in sendMail as Fahim suggested.

Additionally, you may want to consider wrapping these two lines in `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail];`

Comment: Totally right that I should call `canSendMail`... thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

I would say take below lines to sendMail... it would work.

```
self.picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
self.picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

You will have as below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)sendMail
{
    self.picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    self.picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

This is working with me...

Comment: Appreciate the workaround, which is also what I found.  Your answer, though, doesn't help explain why this problem is happening.  Is my obj-c code totally wrong?  Or is this an iOS bug?  The `self.picker` reference is still valid between button clicks -- so why can't I reuse it?  Also, shouldn't you need to `self.picker=nil` to ensure ARC dealloc's the MF VC between button clicks?

Comment: not an iOS bug... you are getting null because you initialized it when the view is loaded... now for the second time, picker is not initialized... and hence it is null... and if you know this much, I believe you should have know why this is happening...

Comment: I'm confused by your answer.  I'm not getting null. Both `po self.picker` and `self.picker.mailDelegate` always return non-null addresses.  If you are right, then what dealloc'd/nill'd my `picker` or `picker.mailDelegate` property?  I'm using ARC, so I don't have dealloc anywhere, and my code never sets either property to null.